# Grouping rows based on time and string comparison function in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe that I would like grouped into rows based on time difference and differences between strings. The original dataframe effectively looks like this:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'timestamp': [
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,0,0),
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,0,2),
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,0,10),
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,0,12),
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,0,30),
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,1,0),
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,3,0),
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,3,10),
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,3,40),
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,10,0)
        ],
    'row_number': [i for i in range(10)],
    'input': [
        'hello',
        'hello w',
        'hello wor',
        'this is a',
        'hello world',
        'this is a new',
        'hello',
        'hello w',
        'hello wor',
        'hello world'

        ]
}

pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

This dataframe needs grouping into sections based on there being 60 seconds or less difference between one of the preceding rows and a string character difference of 4 or less, such that the rows would be split into groups as below. I have formatted the rows as separate dataframes for now, but ideally would be lists of lists to be uploaded into BigQuery.

```
data = {
    'timestamp': [
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,0,0),
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,0,2),
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,0,10),
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,0,30)
        ],
    'row_number': [0,1,2,4],
    'input': [
        'hello',
        'hello w',
        'hello wor',
        'hello world'
        ]
}
pd.DataFrame(data=data)

data = {
    'timestamp': [
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,0,12),
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,1,0)
        ],
    'row_number': [3,5],
    'input': [
        'this is a',
        'this is a new',
        ]
}

pd.DataFrame(data=data)

data = {
    'timestamp': [
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,3,0),
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,3,10),
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,3,40),
        datetime.datetime(2020,10,10,12,10,0)
        ],
    'row_number': [6,7,8,9],
    'input': [
        'hello',
        'hello w',
        'hello wor',
        'hello world'
        ]
}
pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

I have the string comparison function already, but not sure how to apply this to a pandas rolling window function with apply, or whether this is the most efficient way of doing this.

```
df.rolling('60s').apply()
```

I currently use a list of dictionarys for comparison but this takes too long to loop through all the comparisons when the row count is ~100k and there are lots of groups with only a single row.

Comment: `df.rolling('60s')`.